# averaging time it takes to complete a project

Tags: average

Consider a project consisting of four activities A, B, C, and D.
a) A and B, the first activities of the project, can be started simultaneously.
b) C can be started only after A is completed.
c) D can be started only after B is completed
Suppose the activity times for the activities are A = 2 weeks, B = 2 weeks, C = 2 weeks, D = 2 weeks.

a) How long does the project take to complete?
b) We ask the engineer working on activity A to factor in uncertainty in activity times and to provide better estimates of the activity times. The engineers tell us that activity A takes 1 week 50% of the time, and 3 weeks 50% of the time. How long does the project now take to complete (on average)?
c) We now also ask the engineer working on activity B to factor in uncertainty in activity times and to provide better estimates of the activity times. The engineer now tell us that activity B takes 1 week 50% of the time, and 3 weeks 50% of the time. How long does the project now take to complete (on average)? [ASSUME THAT BOTH ACTIVITY A AND ACTIVITY B ARE UNCERTAIN]

(a) is 4 weeks
however i am confused about b and c wouldn't the time average out to 2 weeks so both for a and b the time to complete a project would again be 4 weeks, this answers is sketchy though because it seems too easy to get
my logic .5(1)+ .5(3) = 2 average, 2 + 2 = 4

Comment: I believe you are correct about (b).  However, consider that (c) now involves _four_ possibilities.  What is the completion time required in each case, and what is the probability of each case occurring? (The expected completion time is _not_ 4 weeks again...)

Comment: would it then be .5(1)+ .5(3) + .5(1)+ .5(3) = 4, so 4 + 2 = 6?

Comment: The probabilities of all the cases can't add up to 2.  What is the chance of A taking just one week _and_ B also taking just one week? What are the other possibilities, and what is the probabilities of each (A - 1 wk., B - 3 wks.; A - 3 wks. , B - 1 wk. ; etc.)?

Comment: ok so in the case that it a and b will both me 1 wk is 1/8 <br>
 in the case that it a and b will both me 1 wk is 4/8 <br>

Comment: If the outcomes of tasks A and B are independent of one another, then the probability that A takes one week and B _also_ takes one week is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}  =  \frac{1}{4}$ .  The contribution of this to the sum for the expected time is then $0.25 \cdot (1+2) $ , since tasks C and D will need 2 weeks after the one week in which A and B have been completed.  Now what do the other cases look like?

Comment: ok so case A 3 wk B 3 wk is (.5)(.5)=.25 The contribution of this to the sum for the expected time is then (.25)(3+2)= 5/4,
 case A 1 wk B 3 wk is (.5)(.5)=.25 The contribution of this to the sum for the expected time is then (.25(1+2)+.25(3+2)) = 2,
 case A 3 wk B 1 wk is (.5)(.5)=.25 The contribution of this to the sum for the expected time is then (.25(3+2)+.25(1+2)) = 2
(5/4 sorry that's what i meant)

Comment: That would be 5/4.  Now consider the two remaining cases, add everything up, and you're there.

Comment: adding everything up gives me 6 weeks is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way in which part (c) can be evaluated is to use a "tree diagram" of the possible outcomes (which I'm not going to attempt to render right now using TeX...):

Task A could take either 1 week (0.5 probability) or 3 weeks (also 0.5 prob.).  *Independently* of that (we assume), task B has the same probabilities for such outcomes.  So a "tree" looks something like:

```
                          1 week (0.5) --- 0.25 prob.
  1 week (0.5) ---  B --
                          3 weeks (0.5) --- 0.25 prob.
```

A --
                              1 week (0.5)  --- 0.25 prob.
      3 weeks (0.5) --- B --
                              3 weeks (0.5) --- 0.25 prob.

Since tasks A and B are performed concurrently, the probability that *both* are done after just one week is 0.25.  Otherwise one or the other or both take three weeks, which occurs with a probability of 0.25 + 0.25 + 0.25 = 0.75 .

Now tasks C and D each take two weeks, but cannot start until A and/or B are complete.  So if A and B are *both* done in a week, C and D can both get started and everything will finish in 3 weeks.  There's a 0.25 probability of that happening.  Otherwise, at least one of A and B will not be done for 3 weeks, which means at least one of C and D will need another 2 weeks after that.  In those cases, the project will need (3 + 2) = 5 weeks; there's a 0.75 probability of that.

Hence, the expected time to complete the project with the uncertainities for tasks A and B considered is $ \ 0.25 \cdot 3 \ + \ 0.75 \cdot 5 \ = \ 0.75 \ + \ 3.75 \ = \ 4.5 $ weeks.